S3 PutObject works but List/Delete fails
I am creating a session token by setting the permissions like this. This is done in kotlin.
    val stsClient = applicationContext.getBean("awsSecurityTokenClient", awsClient.getBasicCredentials()) as AWSSecurityTokenService
    val folderName = "<folder>"
    val keyRights = Statement(Statement.Effect.Allow)
    keyRights.actions.addAll(listOf(S3Actions.PutObject, S3Actions.DeleteObject, S3Actions.ListObjects, S3Actions.GetObject))
    keyRights.setResources(arrayListOf(Resource("arn:aws:s3:::$bucket/${folderName}/*")))
    val statementList = listOf(keyRights)
    val federationToken = stsClient.getFederationToken(getFederationTokenRequest(bucket, statementList))
    val sessionToken = SessionToken(federationToken)

private fun getFederationTokenRequest(userId: Any, accessStatements: List<Statement>): GetFederationTokenRequest {
    val tokenRequest = GetFederationTokenRequest()
    val policy = Policy()

    policy.statements = accessStatements
    tokenRequest.policy = policy.toJson()
    tokenRequest.name = "$userId"
    tokenRequest.durationSeconds = expireAt * 3600
    return tokenRequest
  }

The policy json from debugging is as -
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/<path>/"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

The session tokens is then used to upload files to the allowed path. This works as I can see the upload work and the files reflect in S3. This is in python.
But the same token, if i try to do a list or delete fails.
    session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=s3_meta['accessToken'],
                            aws_secret_access_key=s3_meta['secureToken'],
                            aws_session_token=s3_meta['sessionToken'])
    s3 = session.resource('s3')


This fails:
      bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
      bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=path_in_bucket).delete()
#Failue: ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied

This works:
s3.meta.client.upload_file(file, bucket_name, bucket_upload_path)

I have clearly set list and delete in the allowed actions. How is Put working while the other 2 fail ? What am I missing here ?

Delete object should be set for the specific object. In your policy you have a bucket and a prefix (path), but you're missing the object key. You should add a second line in the resources section of the policy (notice asterisk at the end): "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>//*"

I have tried with the wildcard * and wihtout alsso. Both give the same access denied failure. Put works for both though.

ListBucket permission should have a full bucket arn as a resource, without the prefix. It's possible that's the reason it says you don't have a permission to list, so in resources, you should have 1 line that's the bucket arn and another that's with the prefix and asterisk for the objects

PutObject, DeleteObject and GetObject require the wildcard, eg: arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/<path>/*
ListBucket requires the ARN of a bucket without specifying sub-directories, eg: arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>
If you want to limit the ability of users to only list part of a bucket then you will need to use a Condition. Here is an example from Examples of Amazon S3 bucket policies - Amazon Simple Storage Service:
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/JohnDoe"
                ]
            },
            "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET"],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": ["home/JohnDoe/*"]
                }
            }
        },


So i have to create multiple statements where listbucket action is as above and another statment where delete, put can have the wildcard ?

Yes, if you want to limit ListBucket to a particular directory, then you will need it in a separate statement.

Thanks. it worked.  Just out of curuiosity, is there a specific reason why List works in a different way than the other actions ?

If you take a look at Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon S3 - Service Authorization Reference, you'll see that ListBucket expects resource type of Bucket while GetObject and the others expect a resource type of Object.
